# Vue.js is not reactive on replaced array element

Tags: vue.js, reactive

In Vuex Store, I have an array of objects. After removing and adding an object to the array, component stops reacting to the array element's properties. I have no ideas what I did wrong.

I have isolated problem in smallest [project](https://github.com/rafal-mi/reactive) on GitHub, with steps to reproduce contained in README.

Vuex state holds array `devices` with instances of `Device` class. The class has methods `start` and `stop` that simulate some real device actions with Promises resolved after timeout. Each device has property `state` with two keys: `start` and `stop` each acquiring values 0 - the initial state, 1 - the start/stop begun, 2 - the start/stop ended. The Store exposes the `devices` array through `mapState` to component `RunDevices`. The component has buttons to dispatch Store actions stopping or starting all devices, and has colored fab buttons to display, for each device, `state.start` (or `state.stop`) values with different colors for different integers. The Store knows that device state changes, as it goes through mutation.

The evil begins when another component `Settings` removes a device from the array and adds new device on the same position 1. On start button action, proper color of second (indexed 1) device's state `start: 1` (start has begun) is displayed, but the color for `start: 2` (start has ended) is never displayed. In Console, I can see this proper status in Store.

The situation is instantly solved if some hack (triggerable from Console) forces component's re-render.

Comment: There seem to be several places in your code where you're updating an array entry directly by index. That won't work, it's one of the array reactivity caveats. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: In which place do you see such update? All caveats from the doc seem to have been respected, for example in update of `devices` array in mutations

Comment: You should use unique prop values for all elements in v-for that set as :key. Don't use index or name (that can be the same). Ideally it should be global autoincrement or GUID.

Comment: @Ions Lines 54 and 63 of `store/index.js`.

Comment: Meanwhile I have already found that after replacing `let devices = state.devices;` pointing to the same element, with clone `let devices = Object.assign([], state.devices)` reactivity works. This is on branch *solution* now. Completely unintuitive in Vue, hope Vue 3 will improve this.